# Why only highest valued inputs show and the rest don't in printing out dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Hello I am trying to create a three separate functions. One to show all of the records recorded. Another one to show merged quantities in ascending order. And another one to find the total cost.

For all of the records (in the order they are inputed) the code works well except that it only inputs the highest quantity that is inputed for that and not any of the other records. For example the inputs:

code 2

quantity 4

code 7

quantity 6

code 2

quantity 6

code 23

quantity 6

Excepted

Code  Quanity  Price  Product
2          6           39.95            Tea Set
7          6               24.95            Storage Bucket
2           4            39.95            Tea Set
23           6            4.95            Glass Storage Jar

OUTCOME
Code  Quanity  Price  Product
2          6           39.95            Tea Set
7          6               24.95            Storage Bucket
23          6            4.95            Glass Storage Jar

The order does not matter, and I had a look over the code and could not find any error that would lead to not all of the records being shown. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```
def record_cart(number_input, amount_inputed):
    product_info = {}
    for kk in range(len(number_input)):
        quan = amount_inputed[kk]
        kk = number_input[kk]
        price = priceList[kk]
        product = productList[kk]
        product_info[kk] = [kk, quan, price, product]
    for x in ["Code", "Quanity", "Price", "Product"]:
        print(x, end="  ")
    print()
    for x in product_info:
        for info in product_info[x]:
            print(info, end="     ")
        print()
    
def END(number_input):
    if number_input[0] == "END":
        print('{:<12}\t{:<40}{:<20}'.format("code", "product", "Price $"))
        print('{:<12}\t{:<40}{:<20}'.format("----", "------------------------------------", "-------"))
        print('{:<12}\t{:<40}{:<20}'.format("0", "0", "0", "0")
        True
    else:
        pass
    
def sort_merge(number_input, amount_inputed):
    a = END()
    if a == True:
        END()
    else:
        pass
    number_input.sort()
    product_info = {}
    for kk in range(len(number_input)):
        quan = amount_inputed[kk]
        kk = number_input[kk]
        price = priceList[kk]
        product = productList[kk]
        if kk not in product_info:
            product_info[kk] = [kk, quan, price, product]
        else:
            product_info[kk][1] += quan
            if quan > 10:
                product_info[kk][2] = product_info[kk][1] * price * (1-0.1)
            else:
                product_info[kk][2] = product_info[kk][1]
    for x in ["Code", "Quanity", "Price", "Product"]:
        print(x, end="  ")
    print()
    for x in product_info:
        for info in product_info[x]:
            print(info, end="     ")
        print()
    print("yes")
    



    

number_input,amount_inputed= shop()
number_input,amount_inputed= shop()
showRecord(number_input, amount_inputed)
sort(number_input, amount_inputed)
```

EDITED code:

```
PL = ['Salad Server Set', 'Party Serviette Holder', 'Tea Set', 'Mixing Bowl Set', 'Knife Block Set',
           'Coffee Capsule Holder', 'Plastic Sensor Soap Pump', 'Storage Bucket', 'Oven Glove', 'Apron', 
           'Biscuit Barrel', 'Chopping Board', 'Carioca Cups', 'Soup Bowls', 'Elevate Wood Turner', 
           'Pasta Machine', 'Teapot', 'Cake Pop Scoop', 'Cookbook Stand', 'Chocolate Station', 'Coffee Maker', 
           'Pepper Mill', 'Salt Mill', 'Glass Storage Jar', 'Measuring jug', 'Kitchen Scale', 'Tenderiser', 
           'Pizza Docker', 'Knife Sharpener', 'Steel Cork Opener', 'Steel Garlic Press', 'Steel Can Opener', 
           'Stainless Steel Crank Flour Sifter', 'Mineral Stone Mortar and Pestle', 'Citrus Cather', 
           'Cherry & Olive Pitter', 'Multi Grater-Detachable', 'Stainless Steel Colander', 'Steel Pizza Pan', 
           'Pop Container'];

PR = [18.70, 11.95, 39.95, 49.95, 99.95, 29.95, 79.95, 24.95, 9.95, 29.95, 39.95, 12.95, 54.95,
         43.00, 19.95, 144.95, 29.95, 9.95, 29.95, 34.95, 29.00, 84.94, 84.95, 4.95, 19.95, 39.95, 34.95, 
         19.95, 79.95, 36.95, 34.95, 36.95, 33.95, 74.95, 19.95, 27.95, 26.95, 44.95, 12.95, 22.95]; 


def record_cart(number_input, amount_inputed):
    product_info = {}
    for kk in range(len(number_input)):
        quan = amount_inputed[kk]
        u_number_input = number_input[kk] 
        price = PR[kk]
        product = PL[kk]
        product_info[kk] = [u_number_input, quan, price, product]
    for x in ["Code", "Quanity", "Price", "Product"]:
        print(x, end="  ")
    print()
    for x in product_info:
        for info in product_info[x]:
            print(info, end="     ")
        print()
```

The inputs and result
[image]

Excepted [for the product]

code 4 should be  Knife Block Set
code 5 should be  Coffee Capsule Holder
code 2 should be  tea set

Comment: A dictionary only keeps one value per key.  The only reason you're seeing the highest is because the highest is the last one you entered.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted in a comment, a dictionary only holds one value per key.

Your problem, far as I can tell is that you are looping through the indices of the orders (using `kk = range...`) and then want to look up additional info.

That's complicated, but it would work.  The problem is that you are overriding `kk` by assigning it another value.

```
 for kk in range(len(number_input)):
    quan = amount_inputed[kk]
    kk = number_input[kk] # and you are replacing line # 
    price = priceList[kk]
    product = productList[kk]
    product_info[kk] = [kk, quan, price, product]
             # replaces previous value of whatever `kk` is
```

Replace the number_input assignment to kk with another variable name.

```
 for kk in range(len(number_input)):
    quan = amount_inputed[kk]
    u_number_input = number_input[kk] 
    price = priceList[kk]
    product = productList[kk]
    #now you are not overriding previous entries anymore
    product_info[kk] = [u_number_input, quan, price, product]
```

On secondary note, consider keeping qty ordered and product code together, rather than storing in 2 different arrays.

pseudo code:

```
   orders_in = []

   while not quit:
      product = input("what product?")
      qry  = input("what qty?")
      orders_in.append((product,qty))
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply I was working on other things. I implemented your code and it seems that the number inputed is now not the index number for the product name or cost. Instead it starts at 0 and goes up by one for each input

Comment: yes, basically a line order #.  Using that as a key to a dictionary is not necessarily the structure I would have used, but it should kinda work, is closer to your initial design and additionally would work if you were saving to a relational database.  Understand, I am not trying to redo your code and design for you, only point out where I **think** your code had a problem and that was reassigning a different value to `kk` in the loop body.

Comment: Ok thank you, so you think i should use a paired list instead of creating a dictionary? Would that be easier